# My error is when I'm building an ionic project to android: Could not create service of type ClassLoaderRegistry

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I'm using Windows 10 and Ionic2, I tried to run/build my Ionic project but when the apk build starts the following error is shown:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not create service of type ClassLoaderRegistry using
>     GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry().
> - Try:
>
> Run with
>   --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info  or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE:
>   Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not create service of type ClassLoaderRegistry using
>     GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry().
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

How can I fix it? Can anyone help me?